# assign property to object in sudzc

Tags: objective-c, ios, wcf, sudzc

I am calling a .Net WCF service from objective c.I have to pass an object of type 'Category' to a function.Before I pass the object,I have to initialise its 'id'.Here's the code:

```
SDZiPadDocSyncService *service = [[SDZiPadDocSyncService alloc]init];
service.logging = YES;
SDZCategory *cat = [[SDZCategory alloc]init];
cat.categoryId = [catId intValue];
[service getDocsByCatId:self action:@selector(getDocsByCatIdHandler:) category:cat];
```

When the call hits the SQL Server,the categoryId is 0.Since there isn't any category with Id=0,the service is returning 0 records. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: If you have control of the WCF service, try [enabling WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) to ensure that the WCF service is receiving a properly constructed soap message.

Comment: Yes, but can you verify that in the soap message sent to the WCF service `categoryId` is set to a non-zero value? If it is then the problem is in the WCF service not the sudzc logic.

Comment: @SixtoSaez:-The soap message is well-formed.The problem is with 'categoryId'.When the request hits SQL server,the 'categoryId' is 0.For your reference,the xml formed is: `<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><soap:Body><getDocsByCatId><category><categoryId>1</categoryId><categoryType>0</categoryType><docCount>0</docCount><subCategoryId>0</subCategoryId></category></getDocsByCatId></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a possibility the request isn't being deserialized correctly by the WCF service. To verify sudzc is generating soap XML that the WCF service expects, use [the WcfTestClient.exe app that comes with Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) to make a call to that `getDocsByCatId` method. In there request/response panel, you'll see an XML tab. Compare the sudzc XML with the XML in that tab.

Sometimes WCF expects XML namespaces to be used explicitly in the soap body. For example, your soap shows that the `categoryId` element is in the `xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"` **XML** namespace because that is the default namespace. Ensure the soap XML from the WcfTestClient also places `categoryId` in the `http://tempuri.org/` XML namespace. Don't know how you would configure sudzc if it doesn't do that.

Comment: The XML generated by WcfTestClient is:`<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><getDocsByCatId xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><category xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DocSyncService" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><d4p1:categoryId>6</d4p1:categoryId><d4p1:categoryName i:nil="true" /><d4p1:categoryType>0</d4p1:categoryType></category></getDocsByCatId></s:Body></s:Envelope>`. So,`categoryId`**is** in the tempuri namespace.Is there anything else I shud be looking at?

Comment: Actually the element `d4p1:categoryId` **is** in the `d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DocSyncService"` XML namespace which is the source of your problem. Not sure how you can get sudzc to output XML that conforms to what the WCF service expects but if you don't, the calls to the service are going to continue to fail to be deserialized properly.

Comment: :- Thanks for pointing that out! :) And,I will work on the sudzc 'namespace' thing now.

Comment: The WcfTestClient XML looks like this:`<s:Envelope 
xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><getDocsByCatId xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><category xmlns:d4p1="http//tempuri.org/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><d4p1:categoryId>4</d4p1:categoryId></category></getDocsByCatId></s:Body></s:Envelope>`.And the Sudzc is:`<soap:Envelope  
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><soap:Body><getDocsByCatId><category><categoryId>1</categoryId></category></getDocsByCatId></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>`.But it isn't working

Comment: can someone pls help me with this??

Comment: The difference between the two XML messages is that the sudzc generated one defines the default XML namespace once (to "http://tempuri.org") and the WcfTestClient seems to define a default XML namespace for the `getDocsByCatId` element and then defines the same namespace with the d4p1 alias. I'm not sure that they are equivalent XML messages. My only suggestion is to try to match what the WcfTestClient is generating since that guarantees a successful call to the service.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the workaround for the namespace problem.I had to put a `Namespace="http://tempuri.org"` attribute in the `DataContract` attribute of my service. The detail description for this workaround can be found [here](http://johnrossitter.wordpress.com/2011/07/13/sending-complex-soap-objects-to-wcf-services-from-ios-using-sudzc/)